# tcl or sed or shell search replace multiple lines

Tags: bash, perl, sed, tcl

I have a file which contains section I'd like to delete:

```
 mu->doe = '( tr <br>
     tekt  ( tr uapp "(Finction rood (\;)<br>
     ord  ( a b c)<br>

  )<br>

  mu->Koe = '( tr<br>
     tekt  ( tr uapp "(Finction rood (\;)..<br>
     ord  ( a b c)<br>

  )<br>

  mu->Yoe = '( tr <br>
     tekt  ( tr uapp "(Finction rood (\;)<br>
     ord  ( a b c)<br>

  )<br>
```

I need to remove `mu-> Koe` section resulting text in the file should be:

```
  mu->doe = '( tr <br>
     tekt  ( tr uapp "(Finction rood (\;)<br>
     ord  ( a b c)<br>

  )<br>

   mu->Yoe = '( tr <br>
     tekt  ( tr uapp "(Finction rood (\;)<br>
     ord  ( a b c)<br>

  )<br>
```

I used sed:

```
sed -e '/mica/,+5d'
```

but the number of lines may vary and will not be good solution.. 
Either sed, tcl or any script will be helpful..

Comment: Is that the exact line spacing? Is there a blank line before the trailing parenthesis?

Comment: Yes. However, the sed I used was: 
sed -e '/Koe/,+4d' which gives me what I am looking for here.. But at times the lines length chages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
sed '/mu->Koe/,/^)$/d' file
```

That will delete from the Koe line to the next line containing only a right parenthesis. You may need to adjust the 2nd pattern to account for whitespace.

Comment: thanks.. the whitespace is messing me up too.. sometimes two whitespaces sometimes more.. but this will do!

Comment: Perhaps `/^[[:blank:]]\+)[[:blank:]]\+$/` will account for leading/trailing whitespace on that line.